# NEON vectorize sum of products of unsigned bytes: (a[i]-int1) * (b[i]-int2)

Tags: c++, arm, simd, neon

I need to improve a loop, because is called by my application thousands of times. I suppose I need to do it with Neon, but I don´t know where to begin.

Assumptions / pre-conditions:

- `w` is always 320 (multiple of 16/32).
- `pa` and `pb` are 16-byte aligned
- `ma` and `mb` are positive.

```
 int whileInstruction (const unsigned char *pa,const unsigned char *pb,int ma,int mb,int w)
{
    int sum=0;

    do {
        sum += ((*pa++)-ma)*((*pb++)-mb);

    } while(--w);


    return sum;
}
```

This attempt at vectorizing it is not working well, and isn't safe (missing clobbers), but demonstrates what I'm trying to do:

```
int whileInstruction (const unsigned char *pa,const unsigned char *pb,int ma,int mb,int w)
{

    asm volatile("lsr          %2, %2, #3      \n"
                 ".loop:                       \n"
                 "# load 8 elements:             \n"
                 "vld4.8      {d0-d3}, [%1]!   \n"
                 "vld4.8      {d4-d7}, [%2]!   \n"
                 "# do the operation:     \n"
                 "vaddl.u8    q7, d0, r7       \n"
                 "vaddl.u8    q8, d1, d8       \n"
                 "vmlal.u8    q7, q7, q8       \n"
                 "# Sum the vector a save in sum (this is wrong):\n"
                 "vaddl.u8    q7, d0, r7       \n"
                 "subs        %2, %2, #1       \n" // Decrement iteration count
                 "bne         .loop            \n" // Repeat unil iteration count is not zero
                 :
                 : "r"(pa), "r"(pb), "r"(w),"r"(ma),"r"(mb),"r"(sum)
                 : "r4", "r5", "r6","r7","r8","r9"
                 );

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What's a bucle ? Some constraints would help - what is the possible range of ma, mb ? Are they always positive ? Do they fit in the range of unsigned char (0..255) ? What about w - can we assume that it's a multiple of 8 or 16 or can it take any value ?

Comment: Best guess: "bucle" has a Spanish to English translation of "loop". The OP needs to speed up a loop operation.

Comment: Further constraints that would help - can you guarantee that pa and pb will always be 16 byte aligned ?

Comment: @CocoaFu: thanks - that sounds plausible - the best I could come up with was "buckle".

Comment: You mean a loop right? http://translate.google.com/#auto|en|bucle

Comment: yes, it is a loop, sorry

Comment: Edit answering the questions, Thanks

Comment: @Gustavo : It's very important to know whether ma/mb are in 0..255.

Comment: That inline asm is not at all safe.  You modify several registers without telling the compiler.  Use `"+r"` read-write output operands to get values in registers you can modify.  (This is similar to but easier than using matching constraints with unused outputs).  You also need clobbers on the vector registers you use, on `"cc"`, and probably also on `"memory"` (I forget if a pointer type as an input implies that the pointed-to memory must be up-to-date).  You might think that doing this with `asm volatile` inside a function makes it safe, but the compiler can and will inline the function.

Comment: See [the inline-assembly tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info) for some links to guides.  Or just https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm, which you wisely chose for your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple NEON implementation. I have tested this against the scalar code to make sure that it works. Note that for best performance both `pa` and `pb` should be 16 byte aligned.

```
#include <arm_neon.h>

int whileInstruction_neon(const unsigned char *pa, const unsigned char *pb, int ma, int mb, int w)
{
    int sum = 0;

    const int32x4_t vma = { ma, ma, ma, ma };
    const int32x4_t vmb = { mb, mb, mb, mb };

    int32x4_t vsumll = { 0 };
    int32x4_t vsumlh = { 0 };
    int32x4_t vsumhl = { 0 };
    int32x4_t vsumhh = { 0 };
    int32x4_t vsum;

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= (w - 16); i += 16)
    {
        uint8x16_t va = vld1q_u8(pa);   // load vector from pa
        uint8x16_t vb = vld1q_u8(pb);   // load vector from pb

        // unpack va into 4 vectors

        int16x8_t val =  (int16x8_t)vmovl_u8(vget_low_u8(va));
        int16x8_t vah =  (int16x8_t)vmovl_u8(vget_high_u8(va));
        int32x4_t vall = vmovl_s16(vget_low_s16(val));
        int32x4_t valh = vmovl_s16(vget_high_s16(val));
        int32x4_t vahl = vmovl_s16(vget_low_s16(vah));
        int32x4_t vahh = vmovl_s16(vget_high_s16(vah));

        // subtract means

        vall = vsubq_s32(vall, vma);
        valh = vsubq_s32(valh, vma);
        vahl = vsubq_s32(vahl, vma);
        vahh = vsubq_s32(vahh, vma);

        // unpack vb into 4 vectors

        int16x8_t vbl =  (int16x8_t)vmovl_u8(vget_low_u8(vb));
        int16x8_t vbh =  (int16x8_t)vmovl_u8(vget_high_u8(vb));
        int32x4_t vbll = vmovl_s16(vget_low_s16(vbl));
        int32x4_t vblh = vmovl_s16(vget_high_s16(vbl));
        int32x4_t vbhl = vmovl_s16(vget_low_s16(vbh));
        int32x4_t vbhh = vmovl_s16(vget_high_s16(vbh));

        // subtract means

        vbll = vsubq_s32(vbll, vmb);
        vblh = vsubq_s32(vblh, vmb);
        vbhl = vsubq_s32(vbhl, vmb);
        vbhh = vsubq_s32(vbhh, vmb);

        // update 4 partial sum of products vectors

        vsumll = vmlaq_s32(vsumll, vall, vbll);
        vsumlh = vmlaq_s32(vsumlh, valh, vblh);
        vsumhl = vmlaq_s32(vsumhl, vahl, vbhl);
        vsumhh = vmlaq_s32(vsumhh, vahh, vbhh);

        pa += 16;
        pb += 16;
    }

    // sum 4 partial sum of product vectors

    vsum = vaddq_s32(vsumll, vsumlh);
    vsum = vaddq_s32(vsum, vsumhl);
    vsum = vaddq_s32(vsum, vsumhh);

    // do scalar horizontal sum across final vector

    sum = vgetq_lane_s32(vsum, 0);
    sum += vgetq_lane_s32(vsum, 1);
    sum += vgetq_lane_s32(vsum, 2);
    sum += vgetq_lane_s32(vsum, 3);

    // handle any residual non-multiple of 16 points

    for ( ; i < w; ++i)
    {
        sum +=  (*pa++ - ma) * (*pb++ - mb);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: The compiler is returning : "error: no matching function for call to '__simd128_int16_t::__simd128_int16_t(__simd128_uint16_t)'" Do you know Why?

Comment: What compiler are you using ? Which line is generating the error ? Are you compiling this as C or C++ ? FWIW I tested this with gcc 4.5.1 (compiled as C code).

Comment: Ok, I change the compiler to 4.2 and now it is working, but it is slower than the c version. I´m checking why

Comment: Make sure you compile with -O3. It's also possible that your scalar loop is being auto-vectorized by whatever compiler you are using for that. FWIW I only get about 1.5x improvement here with gcc 4.5.1 - you would need to go to asm to get around 3x improvement.

Comment: BTW, if this is part of some kind of statistical calculation, e.g. normalised cross-correlation, then you probably need to take a step back and fix the overall algorithm before you get into micro-optimisations at this level.

Answer (score 1):

Well another solution for my problem taken the perfect solution by Paul R, in the case the w is equal to 8, what happens usually it is possible to use this function:

```
int whileInstruction8Valors (const unsigned char *pa,const unsigned char *pb,int ma,int mb,int w)
{

int sum=0;
//int 32 bits /4 elementos? 

const int32x4_t vma = { ma, ma, ma, ma };
const int32x4_t vmb = { mb, mb, mb, mb };

int32x4_t vsumll = { 0 };
int32x4_t vsumlh = { 0 };

int32x4_t vsum;

//char 8 bytes / 8 elementos
uint8x8_t  va2= vld1_u8(pa); // VLD1.8 {d0}, [r0]
uint8x8_t  vb2= vld1_u8(pb); // VLD1.8 {d0}, [r0]

//int 16 bytes /8 elementos
int16x8_t val =  (int16x8_t)vmovl_u8(va2);

//int 32 /4 elementos *2 
int32x4_t vall = vmovl_s16(vget_low_s16(val));
int32x4_t valh = vmovl_s16(vget_high_s16(val));

// subtract means
vall = vsubq_s32(vall, vma);
valh = vsubq_s32(valh, vma);

//int 16 bytes /8 elementos
int16x8_t vbl2 =  (int16x8_t)vmovl_u8(vb2);

//int 32 /4 elementos *2 
int32x4_t vbll = vmovl_s16(vget_low_s16(vbl2));
int32x4_t vblh = vmovl_s16(vget_high_s16(vbl2));

// subtract means

vbll = vsubq_s32(vbll, vmb);
vblh = vsubq_s32(vblh, vmb);

// update 4 partial sum of products vectors

vsumll = vmlaq_s32(vsumll, vall, vbll);
vsumlh = vmlaq_s32(vsumlh, valh, vblh);

// sum 4 partial sum of product vectors

vsum = vaddq_s32(vsumll, vsumlh);

// do scalar horizontal sum across final vector

sum = vgetq_lane_s32(vsum, 0);
sum += vgetq_lane_s32(vsum, 1);
sum += vgetq_lane_s32(vsum, 2);
sum += vgetq_lane_s32(vsum, 3);

return sum;
}
```

Maybe it is possible to improve it.